# Show that either G is abelian or Z(G) = 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I have a partial proof of the following problem but I am struggling with a final case. Hints would be appreciated to solve this final case I am left with and please don't post a full solution. Thanks in advance!

**Problem:**

Show that if |G| = pq for some primes p and q (not necessarily distinct) then either G is abelian or Z(G) = 1.

notes:

Z(G) is the center of a group G.

**Proof**

Let G be a group with |G| = pq, where p and q are prime.

Let Z(G) $\ne$ {1}.

Then let z $\in$ Z(G) such that z $\ne$ 1.

Then if we can find an element of order pq, we are done since its cyclic group would have order pq and hence G is cyclic and hence abelian.

So assume |z| = p (it can be either q, p or pq by Lagrange's theorem, but pq would yield us our desired result that G is abelian).

**case 1:**

Let |x| = q where p $\ne$ q.

Then we have that (zx)$^p$ = z$^p$x$^p$ = x$^p$ $\ne$ 1 since p cannot divide q since q is prime.

Then (zx)$^j$ = 1 for some j where j must divide pq. j cannot be p as shown above and similarly cannot be q. Then j can only be 1 or pq.

If j = 1 then we have that zx = 1 and that z = x$^{-1}$. But then we have that z$^p$ = 1 which implies x$^{-p}$ = 1. But this cannot be the case since q = |x| = |x$^{-1}$| = p. Hence j must equal pq and so zx generates all of G and G is thus abelian.

**case 2:**

Let p = q.

Then |G| = p$^2$. Also we know that every element of G must be of order 1 or order p by Lagrange's theorem. If there is an element of order p$^2$ then we are done in showing G is abelian.

I'm not sure how to proceed though, I noted that the normalizer of Z(G) = G and tried to construct the product of the two subgroups Z(G) and a cyclic subgroup but that didn't get me very far.

Hints would be appreciated on how to proceed! Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that $G$ has an element $x$ of order $q$?

Comment: Key observation is the lemma that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian. And what could the size of $Z(G)$ be? Use Lagrange!

Comment: @AnuragA, Cauchy's Theorem states that If G is a finite group and p is a prime dividing |G|, then G has an element of order p.